How to add Shadows to SegmentedButton in Flutter
I want to add Inside- and Outside shadow to my SegmentedButton but it does not work.
Also wrapping the SegmentedButton inside a Container did not work, because there a to big gaps between selected Element Border and Container Border.

I tried to wrap it in a Container to add the desired shadows but it does not work:
Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            boxShadow: [
              const BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                offset: Offset(3.0, 3.0),
                blurRadius: 2,
                spreadRadius: 1.0,
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                offset: const Offset(-1, -1),
                blurRadius: 1,
                spreadRadius: 0.1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: SegmentedButton<Graphendarstellung>(
            style: SegmentedButton.styleFrom(
              selectedBackgroundColor: Colors.orange,
              side: BorderSide.none,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
            ),
            segments: <ButtonSegment<Graphendarstellung>>[
              ButtonSegment<Graphendarstellung>(
                value: Graphendarstellung.donut,
                label: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.donutChartShort),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.donut_large),
              ),
              ButtonSegment<Graphendarstellung>(
                value: Graphendarstellung.saeulen,
                label: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.barChartShort),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.stacked_bar_chart),
              ),
            ],
            selected: <Graphendarstellung>{_graphendarstellung},
            onSelectionChanged: (Set<Graphendarstellung> newSelection) {
              setState(() {
                _graphendarstellung = newSelection.first;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),


The UI seems like BackdropFilter/ShaderMask

You will not be able to add internal shadow with the container. If you want internal shadow you will need to use a Stack() widget. Normally you could use a negative spread radius for internal shadow but as the Segmented button is a child of the container you would not be able to see it.
I think your 'gaps' are due to your offsets used in your BoxShadows.

This style was created using this code:
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey,
            blurRadius: 8,
            spreadRadius: 1.0,
          ),
        ]),
        child: SegmentedButton<int>(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                  return Colors.orange;
                }
                return Colors.grey;
              },
            ),
          ),
          segments: <ButtonSegment<Graphendarstellung>>[
          ButtonSegment<Graphendarstellung>(
            value: Graphendarstellung.donut,
            label: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.donutChartShort),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.donut_large),
          ),
          ButtonSegment<Graphendarstellung>(
            value: Graphendarstellung.saeulen,
            label: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.barChartShort),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.stacked_bar_chart),
          ),
        ],
        selected: <Graphendarstellung>{_graphendarstellung},
        onSelectionChanged: (Set<Graphendarstellung> newSelection) {
          setState(() {
            _graphendarstellung = newSelection.first;
          });
        },
        ),
      ),

